# Drupal change row weight in Content Types list

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-content-types

in Drupal 7 you have two content types by default ("Article", "Basic page"). On this page www.site.com/admin/structure/types you can set up a new Content Type (e.g. "My type 1", "My type 2") having in mind your specific reasons. However, the list does not have a row height (ordering) option for this list and I am unable to find any solutions for that.

Given examples above, current Content Type list will always have the following sequence:

- Article
- Basic page
- My type 1
- My type 2

The problem is that when a content manager wants to create new content (www.site.com/node/add) he sees exactly same sequence of content type options and might intuitively choose "Article" rather than "My type 1" if not instructed.

In other admin pages like Blocks, Main Menu List Links etc. I have an option to move items up and down (or to "change weight"). How can I achieve the same for Content Type List, so that "Article" and "Basic" comes below "My type"?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26776/reorder-content-types-in-node-add

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but never figured it out in a coding way. What I did is add a number before the name of content type. In your case, you can do like:

`Content type:`
`1. Mytype`

`2. Article`

`3. Basic Page`

If you want to do in a coding way, you need to hack into Drupal core, create a column in the database for content type, with auto increment. Then in drupal core, you need add a function to reorder the content type. But as you know, you will lose the change once you update drupal. Or you can create a custom module. Good luck